# Docker inside Docker via -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock and volume inside the Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker container which image is based on `docker/compose` which I run with an option `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` on a Ubuntu 18.04 docker host. Inside that docker image I start `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit --build`. In my docker-compose.yml one of the services is specified this way

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - hub
      - chrome
    volumes:
      - './TestResults:/tests/TestResults'      
    networks:
      - selenium-test
```

What happens is that docker image runs the tests and test results from the run go into `/tests/TestResults/results.trx` file. When I was running `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit --build` on a Ubuntu 18.04 docker host all was working perfectly fine, after tests completed I have tests results in `TestResults/results.trx` on a host, because volume worked fine.
Now I need to run `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit --build` in Azure DevOps agent which is runnning inside the docker container on the same Ubuntu 18.04 docker host. All works fine, but I have a problem with volume which is in docker-compose specified:

```yaml
    volumes:
      - './TestResults:/tests/TestResults'
```

As I specify `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` when I run agent in a docker, so all docker containers which created inside of a agent container in fact are created on docker host of a host machine, but not as docker inside of a docker. The problem appears with volume. After `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit --build` finishes its work agent which runs in a docker wants to get test results from `./TestResults` folder, but for some reason nothing is in there as it seems it mounted host machine folder and I found the results on a host machine in a folder `/azp/agent/_work/1/s/TestResults`, while agent which runs in docker needs those result inside the agent container in the same path `/azp/agent/_work/1/s/TestResults`.

What do I do wrong and how do I fix that a container which I start inside of a container works with volumes correctly.

Comment: The host's Docker daemon interprets the `volumes:` line, so bind mounts are _always_ directories on the host.  There's no way to mount a non-volume directory from one container to another.  I have a more detailed explanation in the linked question.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your answer. I endup with adding a volume to an agent from host. Basically, same thind as exchange folder